# Object of parent class being added to subclass ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm having issues adding my variables c1 and c2 of the type Account to my ArrayList of the type CustomerAccount with the variable name sort. The problem states to assign c1 and c2 to the Account type, and set the ArrayList sort to the type CustomerAccount. CustomerAccount and Transaction are both subclasses of the Account class.

Below the for loop in the main method, I tried doing:

```
sort.add(c1);
```

But receive the following error.

```
The method add(CustomerAccount) in the type ArrayList<CustomerAccount> is not applicable for the arguments (Account)
```

CustomerAccount.java:

```
package questionOne;

import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Arrays.sort;
import java.util.Date;

public class CustomerAccount extends Account {

public static String name;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    CustomerAccount george = new CustomerAccount("George", 1122, 1000.0);
    george.setannualInterest(1.5);
    Account c1 = george;

    george.deposit(30);
    george.deposit(40);
    george.deposit(50);

    george.withdraw(5);
    george.withdraw(4);
    george.withdraw(2);

    System.out.println(c1.toString());

    transactions = george.getTransactions();
    for (int i=0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("type: " + (transactions.get(i).getType()));
        System.out.print(" amount: " + (transactions.get(i).getAmount()));
        System.out.print(" balance: " + (transactions.get(i).getBalance()));
        System.out.print((transactions.get(i).getDescription()));   
        System.out.println("");
    }

    CustomerAccount john = new CustomerAccount("John", 1123, 500);
    john.setannualInterest(2.5);
    Account c2 = john;

    ArrayList<CustomerAccount> sort = new ArrayList<CustomerAccount>();
    sort.add((CustomerAccount) c1);
    sort.add(c2);

}

CustomerAccount(String name, int id, double balance) {
    super(id, balance);
    this.name = name;
}

}

class Transaction extends Account {
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    private char type;
    private double amount;
    private double balance;
    private String description;
    private double transaction;

Transaction() {

}

Transaction(char type, double amount, double balance, String description) {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    this.type = type;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated.toString();
}

public char getType() {
    return type;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getTransaction() {
    return this.transaction;
}

public void setType(char type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void setAmount(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setTransaction(double amount) {
    this.transaction = amount;
}   
}
```

Account class:

```
class Account {
    protected int id = 0;
    protected double balance = 0.0;
    protected double annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

// set dateCreated for the time and date the account was created
Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
}

// Set accounts id and balance equal to this objects
Account(int id, double balance){
    this();
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
}

// Getters and Setters manipulating variables to be set to the created account
// Setters have no return value and set itself equal to the variable and getters 
// grab the variables and return them.
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
}

public double getannualInterestRate() {
    return this.annualInterestRate;
}

public String getDateCreated() {
    return this.dateCreated.toString();
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public void setannualInterest(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}

public double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
    return (annualInterestRate / 100) / 12;
}

public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate();
}

// set balance of withdraw to balance - amount = balance
public void withdraw (double amount) {
    if(amount < balance) {
        balance -= amount;
        transactions.add(new Transaction('W', amount, balance, " withdrawal "));
    }
}

// set balance of deposit to balance + amount = balance
public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
    transactions.add(new Transaction('D', amount, balance, " deposit "));
}   

public ArrayList<Transaction> getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account holder name: " + CustomerAccount.name + 
            "\nAccount id: " + id + 
            "\nAnnual interest: " + this.getannualInterestRate() + 
            "\nMonthly Interest Rate: " + this.getMonthlyInterestRate() + 
            "\nBalance " + this.getBalance() +
            "\nTransaction: ";  
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to turn your `CustomerAccount`s into `Account`s in order to add them to an `ArrayList<CustomerAccount>`?

Comment: It just states that in the problem. It also states that c1 and c2 need to be of the type Account. "Store both the accounts – c1 and c2 in an array of type CustomerAccount and sort
the array according to their balance amount"

Comment: Well, then, you just have to type-cast `c1` and `c2` back to `CustomerAccount`s then, like this: `sort.add((CustomerAccount)c1);`  Maybe that's the point of the exercise, to demonstrate that the more general `Account` isn't compatible with `CustomerAccount` but that you can brute-force it with a type-cast that you know will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayList` stores `CustomerAccount`. `c1` is of type `Account` and therefore cannot be added to the list.

If it was the other way around, it would work because `CustomerAccount` extends `Account`:

```
CustomerAccount george = new CustomerAccount("George", 1122, 1000.0);
ArrayList<Account> sort = new ArrayList<>();
sort.add(george);
```

Comment: So there is no way around this? Other than changing the ArrayList type? Because the problem states: "Store both the accounts – c1 and c2 in an array of type CustomerAccount"

Comment: If you cast `c1` back to `CustomerAccount`, it will work. In your code you have already done exactly that: `sort.add((CustomerAccount) c1);`